# How to make a non-alphabetical sectionindexer

Tags: android, listview

In my search activity I am pulling data from 4 `Cursors` (each with a tag saying what it contains) placed in a `MergeCursor`. What I'd like to is create a section indexer which allows the user to move between these sections, instead of the usual alphabetical one. How should I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `SectionIndexer` interface by your adapter class.

Comment: how? you can't do SectionIndexer s = new SectionIndexer(), it has to be new AlphabetIndexer(...) which I don't want.

Comment: Learn about java interfaces and how to implement them.